# what's wrong with following assembly code to read file?

Tags: assembly, dos, nasm

```
;the code read 4 bytes from file and print it on screen
bits 16

org 100h

jmp start 

filename db 'example.file',0

handle dw 0

buffer db 255

start:

    mov ah,3dh
    mov al,0
    mov dx,filename
    int 0x21
    mov handle,ax

    mov ah,3fh
    mov cx,4
    mov dx,buffer
    mov bx,handle
    int 21h

    mov dx,buffer
    add dx,ax

    mov bx,dx
    mov byte[bx],'$'

    mov dx,buffer
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
```

Comment: the code is printing garbage. I think the problem is in instruction mov handle, ax  .... but i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: It might work better with `mov [handle],ax`. And then later `mov BX,[handle]`. We have to either get a memory address or the value stored at the address.

Comment: Step through the code. Is the correct data read into the buffer?

Comment: DOS programs can only work with 8.3 file names. `example.file` exceeds the maximum of 3 characters for the extension. Are you sure your code doesn't fail to open the file because of that? Does the open function return failure?

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer appears to be a single byte. If what you really wanted was an array of 255 bytes then you should use (assuming this is for NASM):

`buffer: times 255 dup 0`

Also, as mentioned, you should use brackets in NASM code to access the value pointed to by an address.  Just  `mov ax,foo`  will put the address of foo in ax, not the value stored at that address.

Comment: True, but there's enough unused (already executed) code to accommodate for the 4 bytes that are being read. So, the buffer size alone can't be the problem.

Comment: If he also put square brackets around handle like another commenter suggested it ought to work, assuming that the file exists.